# How to create a SSH tunnel over 2 servers?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, socks

I have 2 servers, A and B. I want to create a tunnel from my system to server B but I have some limits to do this. So I have to first tunnel to server A and from server A to server B. My goal is to have a SOCKS Proxy to browse the web.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am showing you a very basic way to do it. Here I am assuming that B is directly accessible from A. There may be variations according to various situations.

On A:

```
ssh -D socks_port B
```

This will open up the port socks_port on A as a SOCKS proxy.

On your system:

```
ssh -L local_port:localhost:socks_port A
```

This will forward local_port on your system to port socks_port on A.

Then you can configure your browser to use SOCKS proxy on socket `localhost:local_port`

---

A **one-liner** would look like this:

```
ssh -t -L 1234:localhost:5678 FIRSTHOST ssh -D 5678 SECONDHOST
```

where `FIRSTHOST` and `SECONDHOST` have to be replaced by your hosts’ names or IP addresses.

In your browser you have to enter a socks proxy as:

```
localhost:1234
```

Comment: Thanks, Using this command I have to first run command `ssh -D socks_port B` on server A. Right?

Comment: It doesn't work. I can't browse the web. It only asks password of server A and not B(I think it should ask the passwords for both servers because server A should connect to server B).

Comment: @hpnik +1 for your first comment. I am sorry. I think you are right in the first comment. First you need to open up the port on A as SOCKS proxy with `-D`. I am updating my answer because then my ssh command will also change.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to write both commands in one line?

Comment: @hpnik try `ssh -t -L local_port:localhost:socks_port A ssh -D socks_port B`

Comment: Firefox says: The proxy server is refusing connections. Why?

Comment: @hpnik, just to verify, is the tunnel up and running? Can you setup the tunnel again and check?

Comment: @hpn: You should enter the correct host and port in your browser configuration: `localhost:local_port`. See updated answer.